# xrandr center/adjust image on the display monitor

Tags: xrandr

It is possible to center/adjust the image on the display monitor with xrandr on ubuntu 16.04? The display is a borderless LG 24bk750y-b connected to a HMDI port of a Dell Inspiron 15 3567 with radeon hybrid graphics AMD Radeon R5 M430

[image: image smaller than display]

Comment: Not sure what image you mean. The picture does not clarify unfortunately.

Comment: There is a small black gap between the edge of the monitor and the image. I want to make image "spreading" completely on the monitor.

Comment: Unless the screen was developed as a borderless screen, you are looking at the border that you cannot expand your desktop into.  Is this a laptop?  Is it a desktop?  What's the model of the screen or laptop?  More information would be very helpful for us to help you!  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1003352/edit) your question and add more details.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it's got a borderless screen?  What evidence supports that?  Most systems, even touch screen laptops, don't have completely borderless screens

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is borderless. And thank you for your attention and good will!

Comment: According to the web page http://www.lg.com/us/business/commercial-display/it-products/desktop-monitors/lg-24BK750Y-B there is a slight border on the monitor.